# How to display high-resolution images in UIImageView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

By default, UIImageView displays his image as 1px of image = 1pt in UIImageView, but I'd like to display as 2px of image = 1pt.

Version of saving image with name "..@2x.." is not suitable, images are not saving in file system.

For example, image size is 400x100, I want to display the image on center of display, and it should be 120 pt on the left and 120 pt on the right of the image(640-400) / 2

Comment: maybe you should adjust the frame of UIImageView according to the image size.

Comment: I can't change frame of UIIMageView. Content mode of UIImageView is UIViewContentModeCenter.
For example, image size is 400x100, I want to display it on center of display, and there is 120 pt on left and on right of image. (640-400) / 2

Comment: Have you tried adding the "@" symbol to the end of a file name? Like this "myfile@test.meta@" when saving to the file system?

Comment: @Eugene, images are not saved to the filesystem

Comment: Set the frame as suggested and do not forget setting the content mode accordingly. UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit may suite your needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's quite easy, note that for the versions below iOS 4 you don't have Retina displays, that's why in the image scaling method i'm doing this check first:

```
//Retina detect
    if ([[UIScreen mainScreen] respondsToSelector:@selector(scale)] && [[UIScreen mainScreen] scale] == 2){
```

and then having `image` loaded from somewhere (file, cache, etc.) i'm scaling it this way

```
UIImage * image2Xscaled = [UIImage alloc];
            image = [[image2Xscaled initWithCGImage:[image CGImage] scale:2.0 orientation:UIImageOrientationUp] autorelease];
```

The method

```
initWithCGImage:scale:orientation:
```

is available at iOS 4.0. that's why you need the first check. If sale is not supported, return the 1.0 scaled image.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this:

```
NSData *data = //your data, however you get that...
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
if ([UIScreen mainScreen].scale > 1.0f)
{
    image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:image
                                scale:[UIScreen mainScreen].scale
                          orientation:UIImageOrientationUp]
}
```